Shape of rotating celestial body in general relativity
It is know from hydrostatic equilibrium and Newton mechanic that rotating celestial bodies have a shape of oblate spheroids and this is confirmed by observations of Sun, Earth, etc. But I wonder what effect can general relativity have on this.
I'm not good in math to start from Kerr metric so I took effective force formula from Wiki and tried to apply it to an initially spherical body. From my understanding type of spheroid depends on ratio of forces on poles and equator so if these forces are the same the body is a sphere, if polar force is bigger then the spheroid is oblate otherwise it is prolate.
Because I started from a sphere, newton part can be eliminated because $r_\text{polar} = r_\text{equatorial}$ and on poles $L = 0$ so the only effective part was $-2{a}^{2}r + 3r_{s}{a}^2$.
My conclusion was:
If $r = \frac{3}{2}r_{s}$ then the body is still a sphere.
If $r > \frac{3}{2}r_{s}$ then centrifugal force wins over GR and the body become oblate.
If $r < \frac{3}{2}r_{s}$ then GR wins and the body become prolate.
But looking in Google I found no mention of possibility for astral bodies to have prolate shape.
Question: are my estimations wrong?

Kerr metric is a vacuum solution, so doesn't apply to physical bodies.

The section of the wikipedia article that you link to is about orbital motion. The expressions there are not applicable for the case of using relativistic physics to solve for the shape of a rotating celestial body. I entered the following keywords in a search engine: 'spheroid "relativistic" hydrostatic equilibrium'. (The word "relativistic" is in quote signs to indicate that in the search results presence of the word 'relativistic' is mandatory. Otherwise the results list would be swamped with search results with newtonian treatment.) A good many treatments are available.

The centrifugal force and GR aren't separable.

@Cleonis Indeed, there is a lot of results for your search criteria but AFICS they all are aimed on interior structure of stars (Tolman–Oppenheimer–Volkoff equation), much bigger slowly rotating stars or fast rotating stars. May be I missed a work that show exactly equation for eccentricity of slowly rotating spheroids with size about photon sphere...?

@Cleonis If the formula from the Wiki is not applicable then what is a right expression for effective force affecting an atom on the surface of a rotating massive body?
